# Communication in between different React applications hosted on different domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have two different React Applications hosted in different domains. For better explanation I would say React App A and React App B. The React App B return a Static html which needs to be embedded in the div of React App A. Now the challenge here is to generate the static html React App B needs some parameters and these parameters needs to be provided from React App A. I was trying to using the window sessionStorage for the same purpose but m unable to get the storage value to react App B.

Code in React App A:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('reqData', data);
```

//data is the parameter to be passed

Code in React App B:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e){
    if (e.storageArea===sessionStorage) {
        App.init(window.sessionStorage.getItem('reqData'));
    }
});
```

Please advice on the same. Or if you can suggest a better approach that would be helpful as well. I do have a few limitations such as I cannot use Jquery etc. This needs to be done using React and Javascript itself. We can use any npm package that supports these two as well.

Comment: Are you sure your user will have both apps open at the same time? This would be almost trivial on the server-side, but on the client side it's a gigantic hassle.

Comment: the React App B will be triggered on some event (lets say onclick of some button) of React App A and its will come in specified div itself in React App A. But App B will need params to be passed from App A. these params will be user specfic itself.

Comment: Couldn't you just make React App A a component of React App B in that case?

Comment: React App B is a shared component which is being used by several other applications. From maintainability stand, we cannot add the React App B into React App A.

Comment: Are you using iframes to embed React App B into React App A? or what other method of embedding are you using?

Comment: m using <embed> tag

Comment: You could run React App B as a server-side renderer and use a REST API to make a request from React App A.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable adding this as an answer, because I've never used it with embed. but window.postMessage should work in this case (at least on IE10+)

Comment: we are using ie 10 + browsers. so does it work for you if you use iframe instead of embed ?

Comment: will it work for cross domain as well ?